# How do I join across multiple tables in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 5 tables,

```
product: 
id | name | description | enable
```

```
category:
id | name | enable
```

```
category_product: 
id | product_id | category_id
```

```
image: 
id | name | files | enable
```

```
image_product:
id | product_id | image_id
```

I'd like my join table to resemble this:

`product.name | product.description | category.name | image.name | image.file`

Answer (score 3):

I guess you want to know how to join tables that have no **direct** relation but via other tables? Then the answer is to build a chain of joins over all the tables necessary.

```
SELECT p.name,
       p.description,
       c.name,
       i.name,
       i.file
       FROM product p
            INNER JOIN product_category pc
                       ON pc.product_id = p.id
            INNER JOIN category c
                       ON c.id = pc.category_id
            INNER JOIN image_category ic
                       ON ic.product_id = p.id
            INNER JOIN image i
                       ON i.id = ic.image_id;
```